# Plotly: Is there a way to only change one of the add_trace elements rather than all?

Tags: python, plotly

In python3, I am trying to edit a specific add_trace() plot. For context, I create a Plotly graph with dropdown menus to change/update the plot itself.

[image: Example code]

I am plotting a 3D scatter which takes x, y, z. But then I added a planar graph to the same figure, go.Surface, which is the planar estimation for the data.

The problem with this is that when I change an attribute, say 'x' for the X-axis, it also changes the 'x' attribute on the go.Surface, which should only be the estimation of the data rather than the data itself.

Is there a way to separate specific add_trace() attributes, so that updating a data parameter won't effect the go.Surface parameter?

Comment: please copy/paste code rather than including an image - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example is used for editing the left and right y axis
in the arg of the menu you need to add a list with a index. [0] is the first trace added [1] the second etc.

ps I'm not a 'code' expert just 'learned' python last week for ChemE thesis so my code works but it probably isn't the best/most efficient

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data
x  = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 200)
y1 = np.sin(x)   # f(x) = sin(x*pi)
y2 = np.cos(x) #f(x) = cos(x*pi)
y3 = np.tan(x) #f(x) = tan(x*pi)

d = {'x': x, 'y1': y1,'y2': y2,'y3': y3}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
name = 'Test'

def Graph(df,name):

    #Make fig
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    #Add first trace
    fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df['x'], 
                       y=df['y1'],
                       ),
            secondary_y=False,)

    #Add second trace       
    fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df['x'], 
                       y=df['y2'],
                       ),
            secondary_y=True,)


    # buttons for menu 1, contolling first trace
    buttons1=[]

    #Dynamic list based on df keys
    for dfk in df.keys():
        buttons1.append(dict(method='restyle',
                            label=dfk,
                            visible=True,
                            args=[{'y':[df[dfk].values]}, [0]],  #The [0] 'locks' it to the first trace
                            )
                      )

    # buttons for menu 2, contolling seccond trace
    buttons2=[]

    #Dynamic list based on df keys
    for dfk in df.keys():
        buttons2.append(dict(method='restyle',
                            label=dfk,
                            visible=True,
                            args=[{'y':[df[dfk].values]}, [1]],  #The [1] 'locks' it to the second trace
                            )
                      )
    #Delete x-axis from dropdown            
    del buttons1[0]
    del buttons2[0]


    #List for menus
    updatemenu=[]

    #add dict for buttons
    your_menu1=dict()
    updatemenu.append(your_menu1)
    your_menu2=dict()
    updatemenu.append(your_menu2)

    #Fill dict
    updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons1
    updatemenu[0]['x']=0.15             #Some styling
    updatemenu[0]['y']=1.12             #Some styling

    updatemenu[1]['buttons']=buttons2
    updatemenu[1]['x']=0.33             #Some styling
    updatemenu[1]['y']=1.12             #Some styling

    # add dropdown menus to the figure
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=True, updatemenus=updatemenu)

    # add notations to the dropdown menus
    fig.update_layout(
        annotations=[
            dict(text="Left y-axis:", x=0, xref="paper", y=1.10, yref="paper",
                                 align="left", showarrow=False),
            dict(text="Right y-axis::", x=0.17, xref="paper", y=1.10,
                                 yref="paper", showarrow=False)])

    name = str(name)+'.html'        
    fig.write_html(name, auto_open=True)

Graph(df,name)
```